# How can I filter mongodb documents saved using checkboxes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am building an app using node.js MongoDB and express.
I have a collection that specifies both countries and deposit methods. 
Right now I input the data using checkboxes when the name is "country[country]" and the [country] represents a loop of an array called country with the whole world. the same for deposit options.

and the outcome looks like :

```
{ "_id" : 
ObjectId("), 
"country" : [ { "Germany" : "on" , "France" : "on, etc} ],
"deposit" : [ { "paypal" : "on", "visa" : "on" etc } ],
   }, 
"__v" : 0 }
```

Eventually what I need is for someone to be able to use filters to select multiple countries, deposit options, and other things to filter results.

So far I managed to use /location?country=Germany&dm=paypal

```
router.get("/location", function(req, res) {
  var country = req.query.country;
  var depositMethod = req.query.dm;

if (country === undefined) {
    country = ''
  } else {
   country = 'country.'+country;
  };

  // check if there is deposit query
    if (depositMethod === undefined) {
    depositMethod = ''
  } else {
    depositMethod = 'deposit.'+depositMethod;
  };


db.casinos.find( { $and: [ { [country] :"on" }, { [depositMethod] :"on" } ] } )
```

In order to find documents that have both queries, also managed to get each one separately using $or.

What I really need is to be able to do both, and also be able to scale countries and deposit methods to many more options, prices or whatever...

without writing dozens of routes.

Hope someone could help.

And sorry if this question was already asked I tried my best to find an answer before submitting this question

Comment: Not a great structure. Do something like `"country" : [ { "name": "Germany", "selected": true }, { "name": "France", "selected": true }, { "name": "Spain", "selected": false }]` or even just `"country" : ["Germany", "France"]` if you can get away with only listing the "selected" ones. Using *key names* as points of data is a horrible antipattern when working with a database, which reads **values**, and not "keys".

Comment: Thank you for this refrence. I have successfully changed the values to be ["Germany", "France"] as suggested, while the key is country.
However, this still doesn't help me with cross-checking for values for and / if .
Any thoughts on that issue?